# Actionable push notification isn't appearing on device with iOS 8+, when user force quit app by swiping-up

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, notifications, onesignal

I am using ONE SIGNAL for push notification

ONE SIGNAL is providing functionality of actionable push by adding "actionButtons" key including in payload.

```
{"actionButtons" = {"id":"1","text":"Confirm","icon":""},{"id":"2","text":"Cancel","icon":""}, "actionSelected" = "1"}
```

So whenever push notification will appear on device, it will appear with two buttons "Confirm" and "Cancel" and based on user's selection 'id' of the button will be stored in "actionSelected" key.

Everything above is working perfectly whenever app is in either in foreground or in background in iOS 8+

**But when user force quit application (swipe-up) notification isn't appearing on device.**

I have also added "Remote Notifications" in background modes, all certificate is also set perfect. I don't know what am i missing.

If anyone got any idea about this issue then kindly help.

All suggestions are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation related to how OneSignal handles action buttons. OneSignal uses the content-available flag as part of a technique to support custom text on action buttons and this flag is ignored in cases where the application has been force-closed.

Comment: Gdeglin: thanks for immediate response. Can you provide me a link or a documentation where this is mentioned? Because i need to show it to my client for varification

Comment: I help work on OneSignal, so hopefully that should be enough verification :) https://onesignal.com/about. In general users rarely force-close apps, so this is usually not a big issue.

Comment: Gdeglin: hehehe...i didn't notice that..anyways thanks for information

Answer (score 0):

When force quitting any iOS app, that device becomes ineligible for notifications for that specific app until that app is ran again. So if you're testing open the app, and then close it (put in background).

Comment: Dexter: thanks for immediate response. But the thing is when ever i send push without action buttons, it's working fine even if app is force quit by user